# SQL SERVER: Export Query RESULT as JSON Object

Tags: sql-server, json, azure-sql-database

I am using Azure sql server and trying to export results of a query in the following format.

Required Query Result:

> { "results": [{...},{...}], "response": 0 }

From this example : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn921894.aspx

I am using this sql but I am not sure how to add another response property as a sibling to the root property :"results".

Current Query:

```
SELECT name, surname
FROM emp
FOR JSON AUTO, ROOT('results')
```

Output of Query:

> { "results": [ 
>        { "name": "John", "surname": "Doe" },
>        { "name": "Jane", "surname": "Doe" }    ] }

Comment: FOR JSON is still not available in SQL Azure DB. Are you using SQL 2016 CTP2 in VM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in option for this format, so maybe the easiest way would be to manually format response, something like:

```
declare @resp nvarchar(20) = '20'
SELECT '{"response":"' +
         (SELECT * FROM emp FOR JSON PATH) +
         '", "response": ' + @resp + ' }'
```

FOR JSON will do harder part (formatting table) and you just need to wrap it.

Answer (score 3):

Use `FOR JSON PATH` instead of `FOR JSON AUTO`.  See the [Format Query Results as JSON with FOR JSON (SQL Server)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn921877.aspx) page for several examples, including dot-separated column names and queries from SELECTS

Comment: I have a variable '@count'. and '@resp' which I need to add on the same level as results. I am not sure how to do that in a single query. and convert it json.